# Hive: “type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast”

Tags: flutter, dart

Studying Hive, I took **[this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-local-data-persistence-flutter-hive/)** as a basis and changed **[this code](https://github.com/sbis04/hive_demo)** a little.

I checked the original code. The app works great. But! I made minimal changes for experimental purposes. In particular, I added one more variable to my model.

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Person {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String country;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String surname; // Added as an experiment

  Person({
    required this.name,
    required this.country,
    required this.surname, // Added as an experiment
  });
}
```

Naturally, I generated the file with `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`.

But when I try to run this application I get an error:

```
E/flutter (26138): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter (26138): #0      PersonAdapter.read (package:enemies_list/models/person.g.dart:22:26)
E/flutter (26138): #1      BinaryReaderImpl.read (package:hive/src/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:328:33)
E/flutter (26138): #2      BinaryReaderImpl.readFrame (package:hive/src/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:276:26)
E/flutter (26138): #3      FrameHelper.framesFromBytes (package:hive/src/binary/frame_helper.dart:21:26)
E/flutter (26138): #4      FrameIoHelper.framesFromFile (package:hive/src/io/frame_io_helper.dart:42:12)
E/flutter (26138): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26138): #5      StorageBackendVm.initialize (package:hive/src/backend/vm/storage_backend_vm.dart:86:11)
E/flutter (26138): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26138): #6      HiveImpl._openBox (package:hive/src/hive_impl.dart:111:9)
E/flutter (26138): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26138): #7      HiveImpl.openBox (package:hive/src/hive_impl.dart:142:12)
E/flutter (26138): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26138): #8      main (package:enemies_list/main.dart:13:3)
E/flutter (26138): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26138):
```

What could be the reason? I added just one variable. I fixed all the files where it was required to add it as well.

By default, the application simply opens the box. It didn't cause problems in the original. But in my case there are a lot of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to migrate your database after making changes to your class structure. This is because your class initially had only `name` and `country` properties, and the data for these fields is stored in the database.

After you added the new property `surname` to the class, when Hive tries to read from the database, it expects the `surname` field, but since it's missing in the older data, it returns null for `surname`, causing the error.

As now, Hive does not offer built-in support for database migrations. So, when you make changes to the class structure that affect the stored data, you'll need to delete the existing database.

Comment: You are absolutely right. When I changed the name of the box, everything worked.
Then I wanted to use the previous name of the box. I manually deleted all entries, but the problem remained. Then I used ```await Hive.box('myBox').clear();``` And it worked!
Thank you very much.